# Debugging: search packages for a specific line of code

Tags: r, debugging, package

I've been investigating [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280526/direct-label-error-on-ggplot-with-single-series-to-be-labeled) to find out which package throws the following error:

> Error in if (dif < 0 && any(overlap)) { :    missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed

Long story short, I was not able to locate the bug via `traceback`, `debug` or any other debugging tool, so I downloaded the source of the package itself and its dependencies, unpacked them and ran

```
grep any\(overlap\) */R/*
```

which resulted in

> directlabels/R/utility.function.R:    if(dif<0&&any(overlap)){

and that's where the error is thrown, so the task is complete.

I have two major questions here, actually.

1. Is there a simpler way to get to the same result? Imagine I had ten depends, downloading all these sources would have become a pain. Say, I'd love to see something like 
   `search_packages_source <- function(list_of_packages, string)`, is there anything like that available?
2. Why is `traceback`/`debug` failing to point at the function which throws an error? (`traceback` shows a trace for the plot rendering, with `debug` I have to guess whether to step into or to step over, so I gave up quickly, see the edit below for more detail) I have also tried Rstudio's debugging tools, none of them helped to locate the error.

Debugging in R is a rare task for me, so I'm probably missing something very simple. Would be delighted to hear your tips & tricks!

**EDIT**: here's the shortcut to the code that can be reproduced and a bit of clarification:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, col=cyl)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl==4), aes(disp, mpg, col=cyl)) + geom_line()
# OK
direct.label(p1, "last.bumpup")
# error
direct.label(p2, "last.bumpup")
```

Now, if I `traceback()`, I get a [long output](http://pastebin.com/KBdb61Gb) with no indication which utility function failed. If I `debug()`, I get an [even longer output](http://pastebin.com/ZcC0HZeD), which also leads nowhere. So the problem is not only my debugging techniques are lacking, but also because of the cross-dependencies between the packages.

Comment: If `traceback` is pointing to your plotting call, then that is where the error occurred. It's worth learning how to use `debug`; in the meantime you could download the source tarball for the package in question and use something like `FileLocatorLite` (aka AgentRansack) to search for the string inside all source files.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the advice. I suppose FileLocatorLite does pretty much the same grep, so it is essentially the solution I am proposing. Please take a look at the edit: debugging with native R tools here seems quite desperate.